# Add parameter for specific domains in .htaccess rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains that point to the same webserver:

- example.cz
- example.de

I need:

example.de → example.de/de (but can't be see in address field: example.cz/de)

If it ends up showing in the URL like example.de/de it's OK, but the best solution is just example.de and from server load example.de/de.

I've tried with this:

```
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.de$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^$ example.de/de [L,R=301]
```

but after I click on something on the page I get: example.cz/de and this is problem.

Comment: Possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have this: 

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.de/de/ [L,R=301] 

but after I click on something on the page I get: example.cz/de and this is problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an inner rewrite without R=301 redirect, if you use LAMP server, in /.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /de/index.php [L]
```

You'll see in address bar: http://example.de but not http://example.de/de .

Add this to redirect http://example.cz/de to http://example.de .

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (www\.)?example\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^de$ http://example.de [R=301,L]
```